# nginx not redirecting localy but ok from other networks

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud, openmediavault

i am having troubles with nginx. The problem is that when i access mywebpage.org from the phone or laptop over data connection or on friends wifi it works. But if i try to access it over wifi or my cable connection on the same home network it loads for few minutes (After few minutes some errors appears in the console).

It should redirect me to my home ip 192.168.1.100:2000 where i have my nextcloud. After a while logo of nextcloud appears but it doesn't progress. If i press F12 and see Sources i can see that the browser gets something like favicon css and more. But the site only loads for few minutes.

**Description of my system**

I have Debian server installed where i have open media vault, Nextcloud and Home Assistant. The nginx was automatically installed with OMV. I tried to use Nginx Proxy manager installed via portainer but he did the same thing. I am not using HTTPS in this setup.

**after few minutes there are this errors in the console of the browser.**

```
GET http://taligo.hopto.org/core/js/dist/files_client.js?v=108eacf6-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
login:33 GET http://taligo.hopto.org/core/js/dist/login.js?v=108eacf6-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
login:18 GET http://taligo.hopto.org/core/js/dist/main.js?v=108eacf6-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1)
    at Object.702 (files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1)
    at r (files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1)
    at files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
    at files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
702 @ files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
r @ files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ files_fileinfo.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
merged-template-prepend.js?v=108eacf6-0:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at merged-template-prepend.js?v=108eacf6-0:26
(anonymous) @ merged-template-prepend.js?v=108eacf6-0:26
sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
sk_SK.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at sk_SK.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ sk_SK.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
index.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at Object.344 (index.js:24)
    at r (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at main.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
344 @ index.js:24
r @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ main.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
viewer.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (viewer.js:22)
    at o (bootstrap:63)
    at bootstrap:195
    at bootstrap:195
(anonymous) @ viewer.js:22
o @ bootstrap:63
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:195
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:195
sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
script.js?v=108eacf6-0:492 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at script.js?v=108eacf6-0:492
(anonymous) @ script.js?v=108eacf6-0:492
files.js?v=108eacf6-0:122 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at files.js?v=108eacf6-0:122
(anonymous) @ files.js?v=108eacf6-0:122
sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OC is not defined
    at sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ sk.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
theming.js?v=108eacf6-0:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: OCA is not defined
    at theming.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
(anonymous) @ theming.js?v=108eacf6-0:1
backgroundjobs.js?v=108eacf6-0:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at backgroundjobs.js?v=108eacf6-0:24
(anonymous) @ backgroundjobs.js?v=108eacf6-0:24
files_pdfviewer-public.js?v=108eacf6-0:44 Files_PDFViewer initialized for public page {isPublicPage: null, canDownload: true, isSecureViewerAvailable: false}
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://taligo.hopto.org/core/js/dist/files_fileinfo.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://taligo.hopto.org/apps/files_pdfviewer/js/files_pdfviewer-public.js.map?v=15d058082286d206e4c8: Load canceled due to load timeout
```

[image: Screenshot after connecting on home network]

**I am a beginner in Linux and any help counts for me**
**Thank you all.**

Comment: I tried to turn off hairpinning on my port forward rule in my router. Then the site wont load at all. The web browser shows  This site is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you added nextcloud to /etc/hosts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  the problem was with my provider modem/router. It had a check box for hairpinning but it did nothing. I bought another router and then all worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my provider modem/router. It had a check box for hairpinning but it did nothing. I bought another router and then all worked.